# Vertically align elements in header div (text and logo)

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I haven't used CSS quite often. I always get stuck even when it get's to the simplest layout questions. Even though I am reading a book I cannot figure out how the following works:

I want to design a website which has a header on top, then menu bar and then content. Menu bar and content are working quite good. But I want to have a header with some header text on the left and a logo on the right.

So I have taken this approach:

```
<div id="headline">
<div id="headertext">Some title<br/>some more title text</div>
<div id="logo"><a href="http://www.example.com/~somelink"><img src="somelogo.png" /></a></div>
</div>
```

And for the CSS:

```
  #headline { overflow: hidden;
            height: 224px;
            text-align: left;
            padding: 0px 80px 0px 80px;
          }

  #headertext { font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
          font-size: 20pt;
          color: #000000;
          float: left;
          font-weight: bold;
        }
  #logo    { 
          float: right;
        }
```

So I made the text on the left `float: left` and the logo on the right `float: right`. So far so good. Now I want to align both elements to the vertical middle of the parent `<div>` that has a certain height.

[image: Example]

This is what I want it to look like (the blue rectangle is the logo):

[image]

I have tried using `vertical-align: middle` but this does not work out. I have also stumbled across `display:table-cell` and `display: inline` but I must have used it in a wrong way or it also does not work. Do I have to use another "wrapper" `<div>` inside the headline element?

Edit: thanks for the hint about fiddle; I tried to edit one: http://jsfiddle.net/f5vpakdv/

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I think in order to use `display:table-cell` your parent div (`#headline`) must be `display:table`

Comment: Can you sketch out what you need here? It's a little hard to follow.

Comment: You should also check out [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), just be aware of browser support. (You would want to use the `align-items:center;` property)

Comment: Agree with Zach, I can't follow and there is a nice website that can help with expaining your problem http://www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: @ZachLeighton Sorry. I have added an image that shows the wanted result.

Comment: @Mikey thanks for the hint; I have added one http://jsfiddle.net/f5vpakdv/ and updated my post with a second image.

Comment: Is that what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/3wamvqv7/

Comment: No problems. Glad to help. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this using `display: table` and `display: table-cell`, together with `vertical-align: middle`.

I've removed some irrelevant bits from your original `CSS` to make it easier to see what's different.

To make it work perfectly after you add `padding` or `margin`, check this link: [Box Sizing | CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/).

```
<div id="headline">
    <div id="headertext">
        Some title<br/>some more title text
    </div>
    <div id="logo">
        <div id="fakeImg"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

...

```
#headline {
    width: 100%;
    height: 224px;
    background: yellow;
    display: table;
}
#headertext {
    text-align: left;
}
#headertext,
#logo {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 50%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#fakeImg {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;    
    background: blue;
    float: right;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/3wamvqv7/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use some CSS to accomplish this. Also check for vendor-specific transforms.

```
.vertical-center {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Here is a fiddle, and I added another div wrapper.

http://jsfiddle.net/5o3xmfxn/

Updated version of your fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/f5vpakdv/1/

Comment: Thank you. It looks almost good. I.e. I think the top left of the _first line_ is now in the middle. I'd like to have the text completely centered around the vertical middle. Nevertheless this kinda seems complicated to me. Isn't this often used in practise?

Comment: @MatthiasWeber as others have pointed out, maybe look at flex-box if this doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 1):

I have updated your fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/re472a9p/). I simply added `display:table;` to your wrapping div and gave both inner divs a style of:

```
display:table-cell;
vertical-align:middle;
```

I also made a version using flexbox [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vfcL3x4k/)

I just added the following styles to your wrapping div:

```
display:flex;
align-items:center;
justify-content:space-between;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll take a look at flexbox also. I am now trying to use the `display: table-cell` approach.

Comment: @MatthiasWeber I don't blame you, it has better support. But keep an eye on flexbox as browser support grows. It is more configurable with less code which makes it easy to manage ;)

Answer (score 1):

I would go for something easier like this. Just put wrapper around the content that you want to center and use a margin-top: http://jsfiddle.net/f5vpakdv/2/

```
<div id="headline">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="headertext">Some title some
            <br/>more title text</div>
        <div id="logo"><a href="http://www.example.com/~somelink"><img src="somelogo.png" width="198px" height="120px" /></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
 #wrapper {
      margin-top: 60px;
  }
```

Comment: It's not good practice to add _magic numbers_, like you defined a fixed value for the `margin-top`.

Comment: I agree with @MelanciaUK. Screen sizes and content change all the time.

Comment: It has nothing to do with being precise... it's just a bad habit

Comment: I also agree :), but I would  let a framework do the dirty work for me if I want responsive website

Comment: @MelanciaUK You seem to have answered the question perfectly in the comments, why not posting your answer?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I also had some manual padding/margin in my code at the beginning but I considered this as "not clean code". I am now trying to use the `display: table-cell` approach.